# How to change Datatype of a filed in PFObject?

Tags: ios, parse-platform

> Error: invalid type for key activeSurvey, expected string, but got
>   *Survey (Code: 111, Version: 1.6.0)

Edit:

```
self.selectedStoreObject[@"activeSurvey"]=survey //Survey is a pfobject with class name Survey
//self.selectedStoreObject is also a pfobject with class name Store
[self.selectedStoreObject saveInBackground];
```

Comment: Why don't you add that part of code where you are getting the error??

Comment: Question added. I hope this would help. Just for the reference, when i created the store object i was saving string in active survey field now i want to store PFObject

Comment: Try setObject:forKey: instead

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot change the type of a field/column in a PFObject.

You have to use the Dashboard on parse.com to remove the column and re-add it with the correct type.

If you have any existing data in that column it will be lost of course.